# Can not start debugger with tesseract.js

Tags: node.js, webstorm, tesseract, tesseract.js

I cannot start debugger in WebStorm using tesseract.js. The error is:

> Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:58767 failed: address already in use
>   events.js:174

Running is working correctly. Could you help me to debug?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with `tesseract.js` - it doesn't pass execArgv to the child process when spawning it. `child_process.fork()` accepts a `execArgv` option that defaults to `process.execArgv` when omitted - as a result, the debugger for a child process is started on the same port as the parent process debugger, causing EADDRINUSE. See https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/66, 
https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/102